# Defining value of scanf string letters to be read with a variable value

Tags: c, scanf

With printf it is perfectly normal to do:

```
int dec = 3;
float n = 4.3232;
printf("%.*f", dec, n);
```

But in scanf() I want to replace 100

```
scanf(%100[^~], string)
```

with something like:

```
int a = 100;
scanf(%[***somtehing goes here***][^~], a, string);
```

But I didn't manage to do it.

Not sure if it is duplicate, I will delete the question if it is.

Edit: replaced '\n' with ~.

Comment: If you check e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that the asterisk in a `scanf` format means something completely different.

Comment: In `scanf`, the asterisk means: scan this format, but don't store the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a first "pass" using `sprintf()` where you construct the format string that you then use with `scanf()`:

```
char fmt[64];

const int a = 100;
sprintf(fmt, "%%%d[^\n]", a);
```

- The first two `%` signs are parsed as a unit by `sprintf()`; they cause it to emit a single `%` into the destination string.
- The second `%d` is just the regular code to format a (decimal) integer, it will emit `100`.

So the result will be that `fmt` contains the string `"%100[^\n]"` (where the `\n` really means an embedded newline).

Then use `fmt` with `scanf()`:

```
const int got = scanf(fmt, string);
```

As usual, be sure to check the value of `got` after the call, if it's not `1` then that means `scanf()` failed to do the requested conversion.

Comment: @Igor Thanks, I fixed the bracket. No, the point is that `fmt` is the formatting string, i.e. the first argument to `scanf()` is what we build. See above, I edited usage into the answer for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 3):

For your stated purpose it's probably better to do this:

```
fgets(string, a, stdin);
```

http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: Completely wrong, should be `fgets(string, a, stdin);`. Also the string doesn't end when a specific character is typed (for exapmle ~).

Comment: Thanks for correctly the argument order, Igor.  The `~` part was not relevant when I wrote this answer because back then the OP was asking for something that stopped at `\n`.  The question has since been edited.

Comment: @unwind answer better directly answers OP.  This answer (+1), in the long run, may be a better approach.  OP's higher level goal is only hinted, but likely `fgets()` will work better there than `scanf(fmt, ...)`.  The best answer may be a `fgets()` followed by a `sscanf(fmt, ...)`.